# Iterating through an object with interface, Type Incompatibility

Tags: typescript, loops, interface

okay here is an example code, the problem is in these kind of loops where we iterate an object which has an interface the type of index/value isn't compatible with object's keys. I don't know if I'm making sense but here look at code you'll understand what i mean

```
interface Player {
    class: number
    class_timestamp: number
    gender: number
    virtual: boolean
}

const _player: Player = {
    class: 0,
    gender: 1,
    virtual: false,
    class_timestamp: 0
}

Object.keys(_player).forEach((value, index) => {
    const val = _player[value]
})
```

Error: *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Player'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Player'.ts(7053)*

Can anyone tell me how to iterate through objects like this ? Do I need to create custom types for index/value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fix the issue by:

```
 _player[value as keyof Player]
```

We are doing here type assertion, we ensure compilator that everything here will have values of keys of `Player` type.

But the main question is why `Object.keys` doesn't narrow the type to keys of `Player` type as this is exactly what we do. Its not because of structural typying and has certain rules of [type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). Consider following example:

```
function test(player: Player) {
  return Object.keys(_player).forEach((value, index) => {
    const val = _player[value as keyof Player]
  })
}

// below object has more keys than Player interface
const moreThanPlayer = {
  ..._player,
  more: 'x'
}

test(moreThanPlayer); // no compilation error but there is one key more!
```

As you can see TS is allowing for subtype of `Player` to be passed, and it clearly means `Object.keys` will have more members than only keys of players. That is the reason why TS is not narrowing this function.